# Magento OAuth callback url ignored

Tags: php, oauth

I was working on a user authentication within an App i'm building. The idea is that I will have customers login via the OAuth of Magento and afterwards it must get the Customer_id of that user.

But the problem now is that after the login the browser redirects me to `/customer/account/` instead of the callback URL I defined.

The reason I need the customer_id is that I have to get the orders of that customer with a SoapClient I wrote (which works but the ID is hard coded now).

I used the example for *Retrieve the list of products for Customer user with OAuth authentication* on: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/rest/authentication/oauth_authentication.html

Answer (score 1):

For your requirement, you can use Magento event observer. Do your code according to your requirement in observer.